# Java Spring - How to set up environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, paypal-rest-sdk

I am building an application using Java Spring where I would like to run some environment setup code before my application starts handling requests.  In this particular example, I'm using PayPal Rest SDK and I would like to set up some notification webhooks for my application.  For obvious reasons I don't want to have an endpoint to call to set up the webhooks after the application is started, so putting it in my controller is probably not a good idea, and I need some Spring configuration information to set it up so I can't put it in main().  I'm ok with (in fact I'd even prefer) the application crashing if the webhooks fail to be created, if that's a constraint that needs to be considered.

What's a good way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: When I searched the web for "spring boot startup" among the auto-suggests were "spring boot startup hook". I'd probably start there and see what suits your needs. There are app context listeners, initializing beans, at least a couple of runners, and so on--I'm guessing you didn't search very hard, because it's also discussed at least to some extent in the Spring Boot docs.

Comment: "startup" was not a keyword I thought of using in my search XD

Answer (score 0):

> and I need some Spring configuration information to set it up so I can't put it in main()

The above statement is not true.  You can access your Spring configuration in a main. Consider the following example.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    @Autowire
    private MyService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(InterviewHqApplication.class, args);
        ctx.getBean(Main.class).setup();
    }

    private void setup() {
        service.doStuff();
    }
}
```

In this example, the `setup()` method is called after the application context has loaded.

There are actually several ways to do what you are attempting. Spring boot also supports using [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) and [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html), which both call a run method after the application context has been loaded an alternative to what I have shown above.  You can also listen for an `ApplicationReadyEvent` and you could call `@PostConstruct` do perform some specific configuration on a bean after it's initialized.

Comment: Oh cool.  Is this the best practice for doing what I want to do?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, is would work but makes testing it much harder than needed. https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

ApplicationListeners can hook into various stages of the spring application context lifecycle spring boot provides more e.g. ApplicationStartedEvent

Comment: It's a perfectly valid way to execute code after startup. Hopefully this helps get you started but you will have to do a bit more research to decide on what's most appropriate for your specific use case.